# How to install rvlib?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to install the rvlib on windows, but im finding some issues, this occur when python is building wheel for rvlib
Why im getting this error? Im already installed VS 14.0
How can i fix this "pragma warning" error?

:

````
```ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
ERROR: Failed building wheel for rvlib
Running setup.py clean for rvlib
Failed to build rvlib
 running install
 c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.


 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
 rvlib._rmath_ffi.c
 include\Rconfig.h(16): warning C4005: 'HAVE_HYPOT': macro redefinition
 c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\pyconfig.h(61): note: see previous definition of 'HAVE_HYPOT'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc -Iinclude -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\bd0.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\bd0.obj -DMATHLIB_STANDALONE -std=c99
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
 bd0.c
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stdarg.h(13): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stdarg.h(14): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stdarg.h(29): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(12): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(13): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(131): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(15): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(16): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(1130): warning C4996: '_vsnwprintf_l': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnwprintf_s_l instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(1640): warning C4996: '_vsnwprintf_l': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnwprintf_s_l instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(1662): warning C4996: '_vsnwprintf_l': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnwprintf_s_l instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(1797): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(1798): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(1854): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(2094): warning C4996: '_vsnwscanf_l': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnwscanf_s_l instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(2116): warning C4996: '_vsnwscanf_l': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnwscanf_s_l instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(2171): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(15): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(16): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1412): warning C4996: '_vsnprintf_l': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnprintf_s_l instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1459): warning C4996: '_vsnprintf_l': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnprintf_s_l instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1474): warning C4996: '_vsnprintf_l': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnprintf_s_l instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1755): warning C4996: '_vsprintf_l': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsprintf_s_l instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1776): warning C4996: '_vsprintf_l': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsprintf_s_l instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1899): warning C4996: '_vsnprintf_l': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnprintf_s_l instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(2192): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(2193): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(2216): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(2300): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(2301): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h(2398): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 src\bd0.c(42): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 src\bd0.c(42): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'Rf_warning'
 src\bd0.c(42): error C2124: divide or mod by zero
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
 ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d3kgh8kz\\rvlib_6ae0b3c702e9456c94dc497fe29412da\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d3kgh8kz\\rvlib_6ae0b3c702e9456c94dc497fe29412da\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-62kmmddr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\rvlib' Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: I'm also have the VS building tools 2015

Answer (score 0):

Got the exact same error. I could solve it by installing `rvlib` using `conda`.

```
conda install -c conda-forge rvlib
```